# Coupons not working with Recurring Products in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, coupon, recurring

When I apply a coupon at cart having a recurring product, it applies the Coupon but calculates wrong and displays wrong amount.
But it is working fine with normal products(other than recurring Products). Can anyone ever worked with Coupons and Recurring Products?